# Mysql database not showing for user

Tags: mysql, privileges

I'm really confused here. I have this user that has usage on *.* and privileges to two databases.

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

Outputs,

```
+---------------------------+
| CURRENT_USER()            |
+---------------------------+
| lovemarks_admin@localhost |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I check this user grants -

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for lovemarks_admin@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'lovemarks_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*****************************************' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `lovemarks`.* TO 'lovemarks_admin'@'localhost'                                                 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `lovemarks_rwd`.* TO 'lovemarks_admin'@'localhost'                                             |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I use show databases I get this.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| lovemarks          |
| test               |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm missing access to lovemarks_rwd. I have tried flushing privileges, restarting server, etc. I have no more clues.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it existed. Somehow, after a restart of the server it appeared. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you running windows?